# Is $F[G \times H] \simeq F[G] \otimes F[H] $?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

I tried building an isomorphism with the linear extension of:
$$ (g,h)\mapsto g\otimes h $$
It is obviously unto, and thus because the dimensions are equal it is also one to one. Now, I'm fairly certain that it also preserves multiplication (a simple check on the basis elements shows that).

I'm confused though, because using the same reasoning I could have built

$$F[G\times H]\to F[G]\times F[H], \ (g\times h)\mapsto (g\times h)$$

Which also should be an isomorphism of rings. Am I missing something? Or are both isomorphims actually correct?

Of course, $F[G]$ is the group algebra over some field $F$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule $(g, h) \mapsto g \otimes h$ extends linearly to define a map $F[G \times H] \to F[G] \otimes F[H]$. How do you extend this same rule to a map $F[G \times H] \to F[G] \times F[H]$? It may be instructive to consider the case where $G = H = \mathbb{Z}$ and thus $F[G] = F[x, x^{-1}]$ and $F[H] = F[y, y^{-1}]$. What element of $F[\mathbb{Z}] \times F[\mathbb{Z}]$ would $1 + xy$ map to, for example? (You can also see directly that $F[\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}]$ isn't isomorphic to $F[\mathbb{Z}] \times F[\mathbb{Z}]$ because the former is an integral domain and the latter isn't.)

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand where my confusion stemmed from. Would you say that the isomorphism I defined is in fact correct then? (This first one)

Comment: It is not quite true that $F[\mathbb Z]=F[x].$ More accurately, it is $F[x,x^{-1}].$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oops, thanks for catching that, I was thinking of $\mathbb{N}$. Should be fixed now.

Comment: @Alexey Yes, the first isomorphism is correct. One standard way of proving that (even in the infinite case where we can't just use a dimension argument) is to prove that it satisfies the universal property of tensor product.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

There is a  difference between the vector spaces $V\otimes W$ and $V \times W$ ( the latter also being $V\oplus W$), even dimension-wise.